# On how writers are signnalled in Readers/Writers algorithm

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, concurrency, critical-section

This is the code of the first readers/writers problem:

```
    semaphore wrt=1, mutex=1;
readcount=0;

writer()
{
    wait(wrt);
    // Writing is done
    signal(wrt);
}

reader()
{
    wait(mutex);
    readcount++;
    if (readcount == 1)
        wait(wrt);
    signal(mutex);
    // Do the Reading
    // (Critical Section Area)
    wait(mutex);
    readcount--;
    if (readcount == 0)
        signal(wrt);
    signal(mutex);
}
```

The thing that I did not understand is the use of `wait(wrt)` and `signal(wrt)` in the reader() function. Can you explain, please?

Comment: Take a look at the explanation in my answer.

Comment: The writer() algo seems to be fishy. Where have you taken this from?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (readcount == 0)
    signal(wrt);
```

What is happening here is the algorithm checks that when all the readers have finished reading the content using `readCount == 0`, then it should wake up the writer for writing. So basically what signal does it to signal that writing can proceed back again as all readers have finished reading.

***Multiple Readers but Single Writer*** can be present in the critical section. So when writer finds out that there is any reader in the critical section it goes to sleep and assumes that when all readers are done reading they will wake it up, now to wake it up from sleep signal is given to writer.